# Authlogic - how to set password_confirmation only for update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, authlogic, password-confirmation

I am trying to set up the password confirmation only on the page, where the user change his password.
My model looks this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.validate_login_field = false
    c.validate_password_field = false
    c.require_password_confirmation = true
    c.logged_in_timeout(15.minutes)
  end

  validates :name, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 40}, :on => :create
  validates :email, :presence => {:message => 'address cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :format => {:with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, :message => 'address is not valid. Please, fix it.'}, :uniqueness => true
  validates :password, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 40}, :on => :create
  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 40 }, :on => :update
end
```

and my method that saving new password:

```
  def change_password
    @user = current_user
    if @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:old_password])
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user].reject{|key, value| key == "old_password"})
        flash[:notice] = 'Your password was successfuly changed.'
        redirect_to :back
      else
        flash[:warning] = 'You did not fill twice your new password correctly. Please, fix it.'
        redirect_to :back
      end
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Your old password is WRONG! What is your malfunction!?!'
      redirect_to :back
    end 
  end
```

My problem is, that if I set the form the old password, then new password (eg. **new_password**) and then the confirmations of the new password (eg. **new_password1**), so the new password is changed & saved into the database - but it shouldn't, because the **new password** and the **confirmation of the new password** aren't the same...

How I should set up the validation rules or, where could be a problem?

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate the password only if it's being changed. If it's not being changed, then the validation for the `password` field should be skipped.

Railscasts.com [episode #41](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations) shows you how to do this.